# How to use regular expression to extract groupId, artifactid and version from maven coordinate?

Tags: regex

I tried `(.+?):(.+)((?::).+)?` to test below:

`androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler`

- group1: androidx.hilt
- group2: hilt-compiler
- group3:

`androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:1.2.3`

- group1: androidx.hilt
- group2: hilt-compiler:1.2.3
- group3:

I expect second one to be

- group1: androidx.hilt
- group2: hilt-compiler
- group3: 1.2.3

I have tried different regular expression but none of them works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might write the pattern as:

```
^([^:\n]+):([^:\n]+)(?::([^\n:]+))?$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `([^:\n]+)` Group 1, match 1+ chars other than : or a newline
- `:([^:\n]+)` Match `:` followed by group 2 matching 1+ chars other than : or a newline
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `:([^\n:]+)` Match `:` followed by group 3 matching 1+ chars other than : or a newline
- `)?` Close non capture group and make it optional
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/RlqdYM/1)

Comment: Interesting. I modified yours and this one works for me: `([^:]+):([^:]+)(?::([^:]+))?`, as I don't need to worry about multiple lines. The input will just be a coordinate. Thank you very much!.